# I need to find the limit according to alpha

Tags: limits

I need to find the limit according to alpha. I appreciate any hint [image]

Comment: As it is, the question makes no sense: What is tending to what?? Besides this, read the following so that you can actually write the question properly and not that pic: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2+\alpha(n-1)^2}{(n-2)^2+(n+2)^2}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\alpha+1)n^2+n(1-\alpha)+(1+\alpha)}{2n^2+4}\\&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\alpha+1)+\frac{(1-\alpha)}{n}+\frac{(1+\alpha)}{n^2}}{2+\frac{4}{n^2}}\\
&=\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* As $n$ tends to $+\infty$, $$ a_n \sim \frac{(1+\alpha)\:n^2}{2\:n^2}$$ The limit is easy to find out now :)